# Continuous deployment in Azure and GitHub not working

Tags: tomcat, azure

I set up continuos deployment with `Azure` and `GitHub` according to the document [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/). Everything seems to be working. I get an `Active Deployment` tab with a `success` message and when I push changes to my `GitHub` repository Azure recognizes it and does the update.

But the link to my `Java` and `Tomcat` app isn't working. This is the link (with a different name but the structure is identical): http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/AppName

When I use `FTP` to manually upload the `war` file to `webapps` the link does work.

What am I missing?

EDIT: It looks like the automatic scripts put my project into `wwwroot` but not in `wwwroot/bin/apache-tomcat/webapps.` Should I modify the script or copy it there myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy to a subfolder, try setting `SCM_TARGET_PATH=wwwroot/bin/apache-tomcat/webapps` in the site's AppSettings (in the portal).

See [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-inplace-and-without-repository) for details.

Comment: where do I find the AppSttings for SCM_TARGET_PATH in the portal? I looked at the Dashboard and everywhere else but couldn't find it.

Comment: For the current portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com/), go to the Configure tab for your site and look for 'app settings'. It's for general key/value settings, and not specific to SCM_TARGET_PATH.

Comment: I set it to /site/wwwroot/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps, created a little modification in one of my webapp pages, and committed to github. The modification shows up on the "Deployments" tab, and the log says that the files were copied to KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\site\wwwroot\bin\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps'
but the files don't show up there (their last modification date is unchanged) and the deployment is still as it was.

Comment: The path was incorrect in my above comment. I fixed it, and also tried setting it to directly copy the files into my app's directory (D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\MyAppName) but still no luck.

Comment: It's very strange that it would claim to have copied the file there but didn't. It could be that the files were in use or that something else is at play. I suggest practicing the use of this flag on a test site with a trivial repo to help isolate.